# Тэги в SMARTY выводятся как текст и нумерация <li>

Tags: smarty, dle

Например, пишу:

```
{assign name="name" value="bob"}
{$bob}
```

На сайте все это выводится просто как текст:

```
"{assign name="name" value="bob"}
{$bob}"
```

В чем дело? (код пишу в main.tpl на DLE)

**Дополнительный вопрос:**
Есть такая строка

```
{custom category="1,2,5,6,8,9,12,14,16,22" template="f_newsslider_slides" aviable="main" from="0" limit="3" cache="no"}
```

Внутри f_newsslider_slides.tpl такой код:

```
<li data-target="#carousel-news-slider-2" data-slide-to="0" class="">{title}</li>
```

Мне нужно получить подобную структуру:

```
<li data-target="#carousel-news-slider-2" data-slide-to="0" class="">Заголовок</li>
<li data-target="#carousel-news-slider-2" data-slide-to="1" class="">Заголовок</li>
<li data-target="#carousel-news-slider-2" data-slide-to="3" class="">Заголовок</li>
```

Как сделать нумерацию лишек?